# sed output written to input file

Tags: redirect, stdout, filenames

I am struggling with another issue, this time related to redirecting output to a file (`>`). I have a couple of files named like foo-ab.in foo-abc.in foo-abcd.in bar-ab.in bar-abc.in bar-abcd.in and I want to go through each file, change some small part of it with sed and then rewrite the results to something like foo-ab2.in, foo-abc2.in and foo-abcd2.in for each file. What I have so far is:

```
for file in foo bar; do sed -n 's/text to change/replacement/ p' $file*.in> &1; done
```

however I get the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

I understand that I am probably doing this all wrong, but I want to accomplish this:

```
for file in foo bar; do sed -n 's/text to change/replacement/ p' $file*.in > $file*2.in; done
```

where `$file*2.in` has exactly the same name as `$file.in` with a 2 appended in the middle, but since there are multiple `foo` with either ab, abc, or abcd endings, I don't know how to accomplish this. I already have my `sed` command worked out, it is just the correct file name to output to that is tripping me up.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently an answer similar to this already exists here: [wildcard input files](https://superuser.com/questions/959156/operating-on-wildcard-input-files-and-saving-output-as-input-suffix)

But for clarity and the sake of closing the question, the answer is to change the command as follows:

```
for file in foo*.in bar*.in; do sed -n 's/text to change/replacement p' $file > "${file%.*}"2.in; done
```

now it inputs file foo-ab.in through file foo-abcd.in, does the sed change, and outputs file foo-ab2.in through foo-abcd2.in (and the same for bar*.in).